# bootstrap contextual classes dosen't work with append jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using append to add `tr` and `td` to my table but when I add color to my table rows contextual classes doesn't work but other class for example `col-md-` work perfectly with append but contextual classes doesn't work.

How can I add contextual classes with append to my table?

Here is my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr class="info">
        <th>Row</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my js code :

```
for(var i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++){
     //the class in tr dose't work 
     $('#tbody').append('<tr class="success">');
     $('#tbody').append("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>"); 
     $('#tbody').append('<td>'+array[i].score.toFixed(2)+'</td>');
     $('#tbody').append('</tr>');
}
```

And here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SnHd5/5/) result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append like that: the HTML string you append must be well-formed.
The first append will add `<tr class="success"></tr>`; for the the second and third the browser will add a new `<tr></tr>`.

Here's how to do it:

```js
var array = [{ score: 1.0 }, { score: 2.0 } ];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  //the class in tr dose't work 
  $('#tbody').append(
    '<tr class="success">'
    + "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>" 
    + '<td>' + array[i].score.toFixed(2) + '</td>'
    + '</tr>'
  );
}
```

```css
.success { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```